# How to use sqlite on Heroku

Tags: sqlite, heroku

I will like to deploy an app that uses sqlite to Heroku. Googling for how to do this, I come across the official documentation of sqlite on hereku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

And the amazing thing is that, the documentation seems to be suggesting you should not use sqlite on heroku and then went further to tell you how to use Postgres instead!!!

Is it really impossible to use sqlite on heroku and have your data not transient?

Comment: Yes, it is really impossible to use SQLite on Heroku unless you want to frequently lose your data. This is a sound architectural decision for a whole bunch of reasons. If you must use SQLite, choose another host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has a database offering of its own, based on the Postgres database so it is necessary to switch so as to avoid the file-based SQlite. To connect to a Heroku database, you will need to use the Heroku CLI. That is the recommendation, as you have noted.

You can run `heroku addons:add <your database choice, say the free tier one for example>`. It is as simple as that.

If you try to run `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` you will notice that a `postgres://<>` (now `postgresql`) has been created for you.

Comment: The reason for not being able to use SQLite on Heroku has nothing to do with Heroku forcing you to use its products. The reason is Heroku's ephemeral filesystem. Heroku Postgres _is_ PostgreSQL, it's not "Heroku's own database based on Postgres", and this is just [one of many options](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). You can even use databases hosted elsewhere if you want, you don't have to choose one from that list.